# html time filed change --:-- to __:__

Tags: html, css

I am using following for time selector which gives `--:--`

`<input type="time">`

Is there any way to convert default `--:--` to `__:__` from time field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From chromium you can change the style using [::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/72fef91ac1ef679207f51def8133b336a6f6588f/Source/core/css/themeInputMultipleFields.css?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F)

```css
input[type=time] {
  font-size: 1rem;
  border: none;  
  min-width: 6rem;
}

input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field {
  padding: 4px 4px;
}


input[type=time]::-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field {
  padding: 4px 4px;
}
```

```html
<input type="time">
```

Comment: That looks nice, but only as long as the user doesn't fill in any time. Neat trick though.

Comment: @MrLister try `pattern="[0-9]:[0-9]"` and  `:invalid::-webkit-`.